# How to solve "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" error?

Tags: java, android-arrayadapter

The code is based by [tinder tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5M596DWETg):

```
public class arrayadapter extends ArrayAdapter<cards>
{
    Context context;
    public arrayadapter(Context context, int resource_id, List<cards> items)
    {
        super(context,resource_id,items);
    }

    public View getview(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        cards card_item = getItem(position);
        if (convertview == null)
        {
            convertview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

        }
        TextView user_name =(TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        ImageView user_image =(ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.image);

        user_name.setText(card_item.getUser_name());
        user_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);  // change in the future with user pic
        return convertview;
    }    
}
```

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40sp"
        android:paddingRight="40sp"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        >
    
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
    
            >
    
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                >
    
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/image">
    
            </ImageView>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:text="hello"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
            </FrameLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

This are the swipe, arrayadapter classes and item xml. The data of the users are not important right now.

```
public class swipe_cards extends AppCompatActivity {

    private cards cards_data[] ;
    private arrayadapter arrayadapter;
    private int i;

    ListView listView;
    List<cards>rowitems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_cards);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        rowitems = new ArrayList<cards>();
        //arrayadapter = new arrayadapter (this,R.layout.item,rowitems);
        //context,YourCustomLayoutID,TextViewIDinYourLayout,ListData
        arrayadapter = new arrayadapter(this,R.layout.item,rowitems);

      //  ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
              //  R.layout.layout_item_autocomplete, R.id.tvCustom, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sweets));

        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer =(SwipeFlingAdapterView)findViewById(R.id.frame);

        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                rowitems.remove(0);
                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                Toast.makeText(swipe_cards.this, "Left!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(swipe_cards.this, "Right!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                // Ask for more data here
                //rowitems.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("LIST", "notified");
                i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {

            }
        });

        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(swipe_cards.this, "Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        if (extras != null)
        {
            ArrayList<String> users= extras.getStringArrayList("potential_users");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < users.size(); counter++) {

                String user = users.get(counter);
                //String[] user_details= user.split(":");
                String[] user_details = user.split(",");
                String [] name_parmetrs= user_details[0].split(":");
                String user_name= name_parmetrs[1];

                cards card = new cards("222",user_name);

                rowitems.add(card);
                arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array adapter with the contructor where u are just giving 3 parameters- context, layout Id and the row-Items.

So for your constructor with only 3 parameters `R.layout.item` must be the id of a XML layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!), something like this:

But in your case, you are using a complex layout So in that case you need to pass both layout id and Textview id in the constructor.

In case u need you don't have `textViewId`  you can pass `textViewId` as 0.

like this

```
   public arrayadapter(Context context, int resource_id, List<cards> items)
    {
        super(context,resource_id,0,items);
    }
```

If u have a textview ResourceId you can pass the resourceid in place of 0

```
   public arrayadapter(Context context, int resource_id,int textViewId, List<cards> items)
    {
        super(context,resource_id,textViewId,items);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome Sir, If the answer is right can you accept it.